# Проблема с обнулением переменной

Tags: c++, переменные, sfml, область-видимости

Делаю игру на SFML / C++
и возникла проблема:
переменная **position** сама произвольно обнуляется, когда доходит до метода update (вызывается каждый кадр)
При этом, если поместить переменную position в .h файл, то все заработает как и задумано. Вот код с небольшими комментариями:
.h файл игрока

```
#pragma once
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
class Player
{
private:

public:
    Player();
    ~Player();

    void initVariables();
    void initShape();

    void update();
    void onEventPoll(const sf::Event& ev);
    void render(sf::RenderTarget* target);

    void setPosition(sf::Vector2f value);
    sf::Vector2f getPosition();
private:
    const float MOVE_SPEED = 1.f;
};
```

.cpp файл игрока:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream> // для дебага 
sf::RectangleShape* shape;
sf::Color playerColor;
sf::Vector2f position;

#pragma region staticF
Player::~Player()
{
    delete shape;
}

void Player::render(sf::RenderTarget* target)
{
    target->draw(*shape);
}
void Player::setPosition(sf::Vector2f value)
{
    position = value;
}

sf::Vector2f Player::getPosition()
{
    return position;
}
#pragma endregion

Player::Player()
{
    initVariables();
    initShape();
}

void Player::initShape()
{
    std::cout << position.x << " " << position.y << std::endl;
    shape->setSize(sf::Vector2f(100.f, 100.f));
    shape->setFillColor(playerColor);
    shape->setPosition(position);
    // тут position ещё равна 500.f, 500.f
}

void Player::update()
{
    // тут poisition равна 0.f, 0.f (дефолтному конструктору)
    std::cout << position.x << " " << position.y << std::endl;
    shape->setPosition(position);
    
}

void Player::onEventPoll(const sf::Event& ev)
{
    
}


void Player::initVariables()
{
    position = sf::Vector2f(500.f, 500.f);
    shape = new sf::RectangleShape();
    playerColor = sf::Color(255, 91, 0, 255);
}
```

файл игрового цикла .cpp, если нужен:

```
#include "GameLoop.h"
#include "InputData.h"
#include "Player.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

sf::RenderWindow* window;
sf::VideoMode videoMode;
sf::Event ev;
Player player;

InputData input;

GameLoop::GameLoop()
{
    initWindow();
    initVariables();
}

GameLoop::~GameLoop()
{
    delete window;
}

void GameLoop::initWindow()
{
    videoMode = sf::VideoMode(800, 600);
    window = new sf::RenderWindow(videoMode, "Application", sf::Style::Close);
}

void GameLoop::initVariables()
{
    // init variables
}

bool GameLoop::isRunning()
{
    return window->isOpen();
}

const sf::Event& GameLoop::get_event()
{
    return ev;
}

void GameLoop::render()
{
    window->clear();

    player.render(window);

    window->display();
}

void GameLoop::pollEvents()
{
    while (window->pollEvent(ev)) 
    {
        if (ev.type == sf::Event::Closed || input.k_button_pressed(ev, sf::Keyboard::Escape)) 
        {
            window->close();
        }

        player.onEventPoll(ev);
    }
}

void GameLoop::update()
{
    player.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом примере `initShape` вызывается из конструктора глобального объекта `player` из единицы трансляции игрового цикла, при этом меняет значения глобального объекта `position` из единицы трансляции игрока. Получаете классический Static Initialization Order Fiasco. Избавляетесь ото всех глобальных переменных, проводите инициализацию в конструкторе.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, не знал о SIOF, нужно будет изучить эту тему.
Решил оставить **position** в .h файле, верное ли это решение? Или есть более хороший вариант?

Comment: @TheCPPNoob Нет, это неверное решение. Более хороший вариант описан в последнем предложении ответа.

Comment: Но ведь если я сделаю инициализацию в конструкторе, то не смогу получить её в update

Comment: @TheCPPNoob Храните нужные данные (или ссылки на них) в том объекте, у которого вызывается метод update, а не в глобальных переменных.

Comment: т.е в GameLoop?

Comment: @TheCPPNoob В GameLoop храните то, что нужно GameLoop, в Player - то, что нужно Player. В глобальных переменных - ничего не храните.

Comment: Все равно не понимаю, если хранить в private .h файла нельзя, то тогда где?

Comment: @TheCPPNoob Хранить данные стоит либо в локальных переменных в функция, либо в полях классов. В приведенном коде видно почему-то только одно поле MOVE_SPEED.

Comment: т.е в private секцию запихнуть все-таки можно?

Comment: @TheCPPNoob private секция есть у класса, а не у .h файла, кроме того, это не секция, а модификатор доступа и его стоит указывать перед каждым полем и методом класса.

Comment: но ведь в наведенном примере класс находиться в .h файле

Comment: @TheCPPNoob Почитайте какую-нибуть книжку. Особенно в части областей видимости, единиц трансляций, различий объявлений, определений, и времени жизни переменных...

Comment: в любом случае спасибо вам большое, я наконец кое-что понял